# не получается наложение картинки на картинку при hover

Tags: html, css

проблемы с наложением картинки на картинку, мне нужно что бы при наведении, на картинку добавлялась рамка (вырезал только рамку, формат png) - она у меня ложится под картинкой, но никак не сверху нее. Вот что у меня получается

```
<ul id="history_tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active by-picture" role="presentation"><a role="tab" href="#year1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controle="year1"><img src="images/photo-staff-1.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li class="by-picture"><a role="tab" href="#year2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controle="year2"><img src="images/photo-staff-2.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li class="by-picture"><a role="tab" href="#year3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controle="year3"><img src="images/photo-staff-3.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li class="by-picture"><a role="tab" href="#year4" data-toggle="tab" aria-controle="year4"><img src="images/photo-staff-4.png" alt=""></a></li>
            </ul>

.by-picture{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:10px 0 60px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

.by-picture:hover, .by-picture:focus, .by-picture:active{
    background: url(../images/border.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}


.by-picture:hover img, .by-picture:focus img, .by-picture:active img{
    height: 126px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.by-picture{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:10px 0 60px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.by-picture img{
  height: 126px;
}
.by-picture:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  background: url(http://cdn.creatuity.com/wp-content/themes/reverie/img/our-team/hexagon_border_yellow_hover.png?318471) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.by-picture:hover:before{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="by-picture">
  <a role="tab" href="#year2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controle="year2">
    <img src="http://i2.eurosport.com/_iss_/sport/football/club/logo/large/4693.png" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.by-picture {
  position: relative;
}
.by-picture:hover:after { 
  display: block; 
  content:""; 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 1;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; 
  background: url(../images/border.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```